# Auto-mounting in Lubuntu

Tags: mount, lubuntu, fstab

I tried set-up **fstab** for auto-moutning my ext4 drive:

`/dev/sdb /media/vitaly/ ext4 auto,exec,rw 0 0`

But Lubuntu can't start with this parameters: **Mounting error: press S to skip mounting this device.**

What is my problem? I have three internal ext4 drive - after every restart I need push every device in PCManFM and enter password for mounting.

Comment: Does `/media/vitaly/` exists? Try `defaults` as option to make sure if one of the options is the problem.

Comment: /media/vitaly/ exists - in this folder I have folders of my HDDs, after mounting them in PCManFM. Now will try defaults option.

Comment: @prophecy201 `default` option also not work - Lubuntu says that problem with `/media/vitaly/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, thanks to the [bodhi.zazen](https://askubuntu.com/users/35795/bodhi-zazen) - you can mount partitions - not hard drives.

I fix my problem - now my `/ect/fstab` file is:

> UUID=33bcf4ef-b484-41ec-940b-57a5c18a95ae / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
>
> UUID=199fa164-4299-48d1-9c7d-50da801f2835 none swap sw 0 0
>
> UUID=41d73904-5c69-4831-a7a6-32861ee7d5a8 /media/vitaly/PROJECTS ext4 auto,exec,rw 0 0
>
> UUID=38581832-d6e7-424a-93b9-e193b8402178 /media/vitaly/500 ext4 auto,rw,exec 0 0
>
> UUID=41d73904-5c69-4831-a7a6-32861ee7d5a8 /media/vitaly/BIG ext4 auto,rw,exec 0 0

You can read about `fstab` here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=283131

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab

http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fstab.html

http://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab

or `man fstab` in terminal.

In Lubuntu I have application `Disks` - maybe you need see to the `Mount Options` (in `More actions...` menu). Also - my problem was in Partition Type - I don't know why but I have NTFS, when disk was formatted in ext4. Edit partition type don't erase your data (but backup is always good). And bootable mark need only for bootable drive.

Also - if something not work - try re-order list of mounting disks. I recommend use UUID but not like `/dev/sdc1` - because you may have situations when some partition will not auto-mount because you insert USB flash in to computer (and its new device may "capture" `/dev/sdc1`-name.

If after some changes you can't load your system - Lubuntu (or Ubuntu) may suggest you skip mounting (key `F`) of problem partition. If you not see screen like this, maybe you will came to the terminal. In terminal:

1) `mount -o remount,rw` // remount drive for writable access

2) `cd /etc`             // go to etc folder - where we have `fstab` file

3) `vi fstab`            // open fstab file in vim

4) after edit - `Escape` and `ZZ` (after Escape) - save and exit

`Ctrl+Alt+Del` - reboot your computer.

Remember that if you corrupt you `fstab` file and can't load your system - you can't edit this file from LiveCD(USB), because your system partition not give you access to write. But maybe you can edit this file from LiveCD, if you find solution (I can't).

Another option for fix `fstab` - insert HDD in another computer and from another OS fix this (I not try this but I think this will work); or you can install Ubuntu on USB flash (just select flash drive like partition for install - you can install Ubuntu from LiveUSB to another USB - this flash may be your friend in situations like this - when you can't load your system and need to edit some system files or copy your data before reinstall Ubuntu). I prefer eject cable from all my another HDDs when install Ubuntu on flash - for more safety - I don't want edit my boot sector on true system disk.

For example, why this line correct for my system:

[Device] [Mount Point] [File System Type] [Options] [Dump] [Pass]

`/dev/sdb1 /media/vitaly/PROJECTS ext4 auto,exec,rw 0 0`

1) `UUID=41d73904-5c69-4831-a7a6-32861ee7d5a8` partition "name"-hashcode (only partition - not all drive). We want auto-mount this at start-up. Find this UUID in your HDD-manage app.

2) `/media/vitaly/PROJECTS` - where we will mount, specific folder. Make sure that you have this folder - you need create it. In my case - PROJECTS.

3) `ext4` - partition file system. Write our own. You can see it in [GPartet](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).

4) `auto,exec,rw` - options for mounting. `auto` - mount at startup, `exec` - allow executing files, `rw` - writable. Write options without spaces (auto,exec,rw)!

5) `0 0` - do not make dump and do not check partition for errors.

[image]

Comment: To be more useful to others with similar problems, I recommend expanding this slightly to explain precisely *why* those *specific* `/etc/fstab` lines are correct (for your situation), compared to what you'd been using before.

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/sdb` refers to the entire hard drive. You need to specify a partition, for example `/dev/sdb1`

To see your partition(s) list them with `fdisk -l` or gparted.

Comment: Thanks, this work for one partition (one disk). For another it's not working. I see `Disks` app - one of my HDD in ext4, but partition type - NPFS/NTFS (bootable) (but I don't need this drive bootable) - how it can be and what I need to do?